# How to implement expandable and collapsible bottom bar in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am very much new to Xamarin forms and I am trying to implement the bottom bar which expands and collapses when I click on image in the bottom bar. What sort of solutions should I consider? I have attached a rough drawing of what I want to implement.

[image: rough image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to accomplish since the screen sizes are different. But, what i understood is that, you have a button on the middle of the screen. And, you want it to toggle view/hide the other 2 buttons.

In that case, the easiest way is to create a [grid view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid) with 1 row and 3 columns. When clicking on the button, in the code behind or using command if you are using MVVM , set the visibility of the buttons using [`IsVisible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.isvisible?view=xamarin-forms)

```
Button1.IsVisible = false;
```

or bind a boolean value to the `IsVisible` attribute of the button and control it from the viewmodel